# CakePHP folder utility using cd to go to parent folder

Tags: cakephp

As the title describes, how do you go up to the parent folder using the cakePHP folder utility?

I have tryed `$directory->cd('..' . DS);`, `$directory->cd('..');` but those do not seem to work to go back up to the parent folder.

I have taken a look at the folder utility book on http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/file-folder.html and the API http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Filesystem.Folder.html#_cd but both don't say anything about going back up to the parent directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the directory that way isn't supported, `Folder::cd()` expects to be fed with a full path that is going to be set as the new path, it won't manipulate the current path.

However the passed path is being evaluated with respect to `..` path fragments, ie changing to

```
/foo/bar/../baz
```

ends up with

```
/foo/baz
```

set as the new path (given that the path exists). So in order to climb upwards, you could append `..` to the current path, like

```
$directory->cd(Folder::slashTerm($directory->pwd()) . '..');
```